# Summation of a series involving the MOD function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate the sum of: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n\bmod 3)\cdot  2^{-n}$$

Any idea how can this sum be evaluated?

Comment: Separate into 3 cases, geometric series, quotient $\frac{1}{2^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write the series as:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\left( 0\cdot 2^{-3k}+1\cdot 2^{-3k-1}+2\cdot 2^{-3k-2}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\sum_{k\geq 0}8^{-k} $$
we get that the answer is clearly $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{8}}=\color{red}{\large\frac{8}{7}}.$

Answer (score 0):

Show that the series is absolutely convergent and then use that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n \mod 3)\cdot 2^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-3k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2 \cdot 2^{-(3k+1)}$$

The rest is simple calculation of geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

The $\bmod$ factor is periodic with period $3$ so that deducing the three first terms, which evaluate to $1$, has the same effect as dividing the sum by $2^3$.

Hence,

$$\frac87.$$